# Sublime Text Build For Executing Indesign .jsx Scripts on Windows

Tags: sublimetext3, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to write a sublime text build to execute an indesign jsx script strait from sublime text on Windows. For the Mac there's a build by Basil https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/tree/master/extras/Sublime%20Text that consists of a build and an osascript.

The build is:

```
      // copy this file to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User
   {
       "cmd": ["osascript", "$packages/Basiljs/run_idscript_6.0.scpt", "$file"]
    }
```

The osascript is:

```
 --usage:
--osascript run.scpt myscript.jsx

on run argv
set aScriptPath to "#include \"" & item 1 of argv & "\""
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
do script aScriptPath language javascript
end tell
end run
```

I would like to do this with For Windows for my build I have done

```
  {
   "cmd": ["wscript", "$packages/creative-scripts/run_indesign.vbs", "$file"]
  }
```

and for my wscript I have done

```
myScript = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
Set myInDesign = CreateObject("InDesign.Application")
MsgBox myScript ' just to check the path
Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFile = myFileSystemObject.GetFile(myScript) 
myInDesign.DoScript myFile, 1246973031
```

I was getting the following error message
Error: Object required: 'idScriptLanguage'
Code: 800A01A8

I have now edited the script putting in the change as per Vlad's answer and it work very well now.

Trevor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the idScriptLanguage.idJavascript with it's actual value (1246973031) will solve the problem.

Comment: Excellent solution Vlad.

Comment: It works nicely with $.writeln also will work without using a #target (if one is lucky to have the correct application and version open) works with Illustrator as well as InDesign,  probably works with the other applications as well, I didn't test yet.  One interesting aspect to it is that different versions of the ESTK will open depending on the app version being used.  I didn't bother using the build I came up with because of the $.writeln problem but this fix seems pretty solid and I think I shall use it. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution with this sublime build **:-)**

```
 {
    // for script to run must have #target "InDesign-7.0" "InDesign" Ietc. in it :-( otherwise the script will just open in the estk
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC\\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe", "-run", "$file"]
 }
```

Above is for a 64 bit system just remove the " (x86)" for a 32 bit one

Take note of the need for the **#target**

It will come up with a standard warning "Do you about to run .... Do you wish to run the script?"

So one needs to press y space or enter. Not too big a deal, but to suppress this one can put the script into the "Adobe Scripts" folder in Document then the warning won't come up.

See https://forums.adobe.com/message/4689581 and http://jfli04.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/how-to-run-js-in-estk-with-command-line.htm